# Python module smtplib doesn't send mail

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a program that logins with a Gmail id and sends a mail to a provided id.

```
import smtplib

email = input('Enter your email\n')
password = input('Enter your password\n')
reciever = input("To whom you want to send?\n")
content = input("Enter content below:\n")




mail= smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
mail.ehlo()
mail.starttls()
mail.login(email,password)
mail.send_message(email,reciever,content)
```

But when I execute the program I get this error...

```
Enter your email
soham.nandy2006@gmail.com
Enter your password
x
To whom you want to send?
soham.nandy@outlook.com
Enter content below:
HELLOOOO
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/soham/Desktop/Python Crack/main.py", line 15, in <module>
    mail.send_message(email,reciever,content)
  File "C:\Users\soham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\smtplib.py", line 928, in send_message
    resent = msg.get_all('Resent-Date')
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get_all'
PS C:\Users\soham\Desktop\Python Crack>
```

P.S- I am writing x instead of my password for security issue (In the program the password is correct)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python smtplib send\_message() failing, returning AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get\_all'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29899542/python-smtplib-send-message-failing-returning-attributeerror-str-object-ha)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass `MIMEMultipart` object, not strings, when you use `send_message`:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

# collect data from user
email = input('Enter your email\n')
password = input('Enter your password\n')
reciever = input("To whom you want to send?\n")
content = input("Enter content below:\n")

# set up a server
mail = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
mail.ehlo()
mail.starttls()
mail.login(email, password)

# create and specify parts of the email
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = email
msg['To'] = reciever
msg['Subject'] = 'sample subject' # maybe you want to collect it as well?

msg.attach(MIMEText(content, 'plain'))

mail.send_message(msg)
mail.quit()
```

Comment: msg = MIMEMultipart() not defined

Comment: `from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart` and `from email.mime.text import MIMEText`. Answer edited.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/soham/Desktop/Python Crack/main.py", line 20, in <module>
    msg['Subject'] = subject # maybe you want to collect it as well?
NameError: name 'subject' is not defined
PS C:\Users\soham>

Comment: eh, this was a suggestion for you that subject is quite relevant in mail.... delete this line or change it to:  `msg['Subject'] = 'test subject'`

Comment: oh, I figured it out later, thanks a lot. I appreciate ur help.

Comment: my program was working but suddenly now it says there isn't a package named email

Comment: maybe you changed environment? check list of your installed packages in CMD: `pip list`

Comment: I figured it out, I had named my file email.py which caused python confusion

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong function to send your email. You should use `mail.sendmail()` instead of `mail.send_message()`. The difference is the order of the arguements and in the first function, the message is a string, in the second it is a `Message` object.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.sendmail