# smtplib unrecognised keyword 'subject'

Tags: python, python-3.x, sendmail, smtplib, email-client

I want to send an email by smtplib but it give me error

```
    server.send_message(user_name, to, message, subject=subject)
TypeError: send_message() got an unexpected keyword argument 'subject'
```

This code

```
    import smtplib
    user_name = 'my@gmail.com'
    password = '*******'
    to = ['my@gmail.com', 'other_email@gmail.com']
    subject = 'Theme'
    message = 'Test message'
    server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
    server.ehlo()
    server.login(user_name, password)
    server.send_message(user_name, to, message, subject=subject)
    server.close()
```

I try delete subject from code but it give me new error

```
      File "C:\\lib\smtplib.py", line 939, in send_message
        resent = msg.get_all('Resent-Date')
    AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get_all'
```

How i can fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29899542/python-smtplib-send-message-failing-returning-attributeerror-str-object-ha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `sendmail()` instead of `send_message()`

```py
import smtplib
user_name = 'my@gmail.com'
password = '*******'
to = ['my@gmail.com', 'other_email@gmail.com']
subject = 'Theme'
message = 'Test message'
email_message = 'Subject: {}\n\n{}'.format(subject, message) 
server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
server.ehlo()
server.login(user_name, password)
server.send_message(user_name, to, email_message)
server.close()
```

Ref:

1. [Python smtplib send_message() failing, returning AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get_all'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29899542/python-smtplib-send-message-failing-returning-attributeerror-str-object-ha)
2. [Python: "subject" not shown when sending email using smtplib module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7232088/python-subject-not-shown-when-sending-email-using-smtplib-module)